# Very affectionate and almost always purring cat

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

My 1 year old male cat has loved belly rubs ever since he was a kitten- he's only ever lived with us and is both an indoor and outdoor cat. He is always snuggling up to us, rolling over, and letting us pet his belly, or purring his super loud purr. When I get home he sits on my lap and guides my hand to his head with his paw and purrs even when I'm not petting him. (There's four other people in the house so I doubt its a lack of attention) I've never had a cat so affectionate and am curious as to what this means.